# Undefined index error while editing categories in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Undefined index error's while editing categories in Prestashop 1.6. I couldn't find what went wrong.

Complete Error Log:

Notice on line 550 in file /home1/cornesi9/public_html/mywebsite/controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php
[8] Undefined index: medium

Notice on line 41 in file /home1/cornesi9/public_html/mywebsite/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code
[8] Undefined index: format

Notice on line 41 in file /home1/cornesi9/public_html/mywebsite/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code
[8] Trying to get property of non-object

Notice on line 41 in file /home1/cornesi9/public_html/mywebsite/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code
[8] Undefined index: format

Notice on line 41 in file /home1/cornesi9/public_html/mywebsite/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code
[8] Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Was this working? or was something changed? Generally this means there are undefined variables in the template. Could be caused by something removed perhaps?

Comment: @alexj Thanks man. At least some one replied. No. it's not working. The errors still exist. I tried to replace the file with a new prestasop installation(Only files those who have problems but, not working.) What you mean by there are undefined variables in the template...? I did changed my website template, is that is what caused this issue ..?